# How can I have a custom URL for Episerver Edit mode?

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I wanted to have a custom URL for the pages displayed in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You need to change some places in web.config:

```
<episerver.packaging protectedVirtualPath="~/episerver" />
```

and

```
<applicationSettings uiUrl="~/episerver/CMS/" />
```

and

`<virtualPathProviders>` entry for ProtectedModules, `<add name="ProtectedModules" virtualPath="~/episerver/" />`

and all the `<location>` elements pointing to "episerver...".